# Canvas not resizing automatically in WinJS

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I just ported my game to Win8JS. It was fairly simple surprisingly. But I made the game with a fixed resolution in mind. I have explicitly set a resolution of 800 x 500 pixels on all canvas elements but I want them to scale automatically to all resolutions on the simulator - how do I achieve that?

This is how my game looks right now http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC571329.png  :(

On the same link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx

it says "canvas automatically fills the empty space" but it doesn't in my case probably because I have pre defined fixed height and width?

How do I go on about this? If I remove the width and height then the canvas won't be visible. Fairly new to all this - would appreciate help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give a control a fixed size it won't resize.  If you have an explicit layout you need then your link recommends using the [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229771.aspx).

> Scales a single child element to fill the available space without
>   resizing it. This control reacts to changes in the size of the
>   container as well as changes in size of the child element. For
>   example, a media query may result in a change in aspect ratio.

Put your canvas in a viewbox and it should scale for you.

```
<body>
    <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ViewBox">
        <div class="fixedlayout">
            <p>Content goes here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


 //.css file
.fixedlayout {
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
    -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
    display: -ms-grid;
    height: 768px;
    width: 1024px;
}
```

Edit:

I tested this and it worked:

```
<body>
    <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ViewBox">
        <div class="fixedlayout">
            <canvas id="canvas"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

window.onload = draw;
function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 215, 0)";
    context.fillRect(15, 15, 55, 50);
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
    context.fillRect(40, 40, 45, 40);
}

.fixedlayout {
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
    -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
    display: -ms-grid;
    height: 768px;
    width: 1024px;
}
```

Comment: I did try but nothing really happened. Do I have to change the css of div class inside viewbox tag for it to work? Can I add all my canvas elements inside (if yes then it doesn't work for me..).

Comment: <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ViewBox">
  <div class="ScaleClass"> <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500" " ></canvas> </div>
 </div>

Comment: See the example here: http://codefoster.com/post/2012/06/29/How-the-WinJSUIViewBox-Actually-Works.aspx

Comment: The second link is interesting. What should I put inside height and width attribute .fixedlayout ?

Comment: I would have to try it myself.  I might have time later to investigate, but I'm on win 7 at the moment.

Comment: It would be great if you could try - would help me out a lot. Thank you :)

Comment: To test this I created a Fixed Layout App. This creates a file called default.html which starts out with `<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ViewBox"> <div class="fixedlayout"> <p>Content goes here</p> </div> </div>` as the body. I changed the `<p>Content goes here</p>` to `<img src="images/logo.png" />` and it scales as excepted. Can you try posting more of your code?

Comment: I need to resize a  canvas not an image..have you tried it with a canvas?

Comment: I think your problem is that you set the height and width of the canvas.  See my edit.

Comment: Hey! I think it has started scaling but it's stuck at one resolution which is showing only a part of the background :( any idea what's going wrong?
edit: It does fill up the screen at the resolution stated but it isn't really proper as it shows only  a part of the canvas.

Comment: If you post your code I can take a look.  It's very difficult without knowing how you're doing it.

Comment: It's the same. I think I am going to mess around more but thank you very much for all the help. Marking it as answer. Good day! :)

Comment: Well, I meant your js but if that's good enough then good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The key seems to be this - "Ensure that the ViewBox control is sized to 100% width and height." Try putting a style="width:100%;height:100%" for the ViewBox div. And remove the canvas height and width.

Comment: Tried. It just shows a fragment of the canvas :(

you mean this, right? 

<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ViewBox" style="width:100%;height:100%">

Comment: will take one last shot at this. Remove the divs and style the canvas directly with "width:100%;height:100%;" Unfortunately, I don't have win8 installed to test this, but it works for plain HTML.